# Cannot copy database or import exported database script

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to copy a database.

From PHPMyAdmin, I've tried both the copy database functionality and the importing of an exported script. In both cases, I get this:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'e.request_id`request_id' in 'group statement'
```

After the copy/import, since the error above relates to views, they will be missing in the new database.

In the old database, the view works. If I run `show create view my_view_name`, paste into the SQL tab of the new database, the view gets created without any problems.

Any ideas why manually running the create view statement works, but not through the copy/import process?

**Edit #1**

I just spotted the issue above.

I'm assuming the database copy and export reuse the same SQL generation process? They both complain here - note the extra `request_id` in the export script:

```
GROUP BY `sl`.`intake_type_id`, `e`.`request_id``request_id`  ;
```

The `show create view` doesn't produce the same code:

```
group by `sl`.`intake_type_id`,`e`.`request_id`
```

In the old database, when editing the view, I don't see any issues either:

```
GROUP BY
    `sl`.`intake_type_id`,
    `e`.`request_id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually fixing the produced SQL file to remove the issue with the `group by` and other tidbits.